# Build URL from form fields with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a URL builder form with JavaScript or jQuery.

Basically, it will take the value of the two form fields, add them to a preset URL and show it on a third field on submit.

The resulting URL might be http://example.com/index.php?variable1=12&variable2=56

Now, this isn't the "action" of the form and the application can't read a URL (to grab the variables), so it has to be done on the page.

The resulting URL will be shown in the field named "url".

Here's a sample of the form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>Variable 1
      <input type="text" name="variable1" id="variable1" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Variable 2
      <input type="text" name="variable2" id="variable2" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>URL
      <input type="text" name="url" id="url" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Where does the preset url come from?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Answer (score 28, accepted):

jQuery has [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) which builds the query string values.

So if you want to do the entire form:

```
alert($("#form1").serialize());
```

If you want to do only a few fields, then just make the selector select those fields.

```
alert($("#variable1, #variable2").serialize());
```

Answer (score 8):

Use something like...

```
var inputs = $('#form1').find('input[type=text]').not('#url');
var str = "http://www.base.url/path/file.ext?"
inputs.each(function (i, item) {
    str += encodeURIComponent(item.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(item.value) + "&";
});
$('#url').val(str);
```

This will select all `<input>`s on in `form1` with `type='text'`, and concatenate them into a query string. See [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

---

Orrrr.....you could just use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). [Thank you, prodigitalson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006991/build-url-from-form-fields-with-javascript-or-jquery#comment4293376_4007029).

Comment: Since youre already using jQ, why do all that when you can just use `$(inputSelector).serialize();`?

Comment: You shoud include this:   if(i<$(this).length){str +="&";}   in the last line of each loop, because last time you have a trimming "&".

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
var partFields = '#variable1,#variable2';

$(partFields).change(function(){
  var url = 'static/URL/to/file.php?';
  $('#url').val(url + $(partFields).serialize());
});
```

However, unless you want people to be able to override the URL, you might want to use a hidden field and a regular element for display and submission of the URL value in which case you'd have something like the following:

```
var partFields = '#variable1,#variable2';

$(partFields).change(function(){
  var url = 'static/URL/to/file.php?';
  var urlValue = url + $(partFields).serialize();
  $('#url-display').text(urlValue); // Set the displaying element
  $('#url').val(urlValue); // Set the hidden input value
});
```

Comment: I would use @clarkf line: var partFields = $('#form1').find('input[type=text]').not('#url'); Here you have the working demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dactivo/4Nmcx/